# Slow DNS Resolution after upgrade

Tags: wireless, 12.10, dns, google

I've been having some strange issues with what also seems to be a resolution issue. Some sites load (very slowly), others time out. Not sure how to troubleshoot this one but would appreciate help, and will update my question with more data as it's requested.

What I've tried:

`dpkg-reconfigure bind9-host` : read about this in a seemingly related post

```
dig @nameserver-ip askubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @nameserver-ip askubuntu.com ; 
(2 servers found) ;; global options: +cmd ;; connection timed out; 
no servers could be reached
```

Background:

I recently tried to upgrade to 12.10 directly from 12.04. This failed for whatever reason, to grub rescue. Allright, no problem, on another computer I get a usb key setup for installation, install (delete everything).

Load up, connect to wifi, no problems to speak of, install goes smoothly. After which, I didn't use the machine.

Now, this is a fresh install, so why is my DNS set to Google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4)? Strange indeed. But, perhaps a fragment from the previous install. And not my actual question but noted just in case it's relevant.

Comment: I'm confused as to how this could be an artifact from a previous install if this is a fresh install.  Did you add that on a previous version on the same filesystem?

Comment: First, I tried to upgrade. When that failed (grub rescue), I "delete everything and install Ubuntu" from the install menu. So yes, I'm confused as well. Yes it was set that way when 12.10 was installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the network manager connection settings under [Network icon]->edit connections->[your connection]->edit->IPv4 settings?

If the DNS domains/addresses are hard coded to google's DNS there, you can try selecting the "Automatic(DHCP)" option in the "Method" dropdown and saving the connection?

Try: `dpkg-reconfigure bind9-host` and then rebooting.

Comment: It's strange because it IS set to automatic and it IS showing google DNS.

Comment: So it doesn't say "Automatic (address only)" and still honors the value in the text box? That **is** strange...
Here's how to get rid of it - Select "Automatic (address only)" from the dropdown, that should make the field editable. Delete the values, select "Automatic" back in the dropdown menu and save the settings.

Comment: No, it says automatic(DHCP) and there is nothing in the box - yet, connection information shows 8.8.8.8

Comment: There are no values in the field to which you refer - that's why I'm puzzled by this.

Comment: Okay, got that. To be fair, I have found the google DNS to be pretty fast most of the time. Is there a network admin for this network or is your home network?

I tried your original command and even mine is timing out.
This worked however:

`dig @ns1.google.com http://www.askubuntu.com`
Encouraged I tried both 
`dig @8.8.4.4 http://www.askubuntu.com`
and
`dig @8.8.4.4 http://www.askubuntu.com`

Both worked. Maybe the framing of the query is wrong.

Comment: Home network, all computers are running ubuntu other one is on 12.04 though. This is just a laptop (ie, it can break).

Comment: I rebooted, and everything seems to be working fine now anyways. Another mystery.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I've had the same problem and found my solution here:

https://www.slightfuture.com/how-to/debian-dns-resolv.html

In short, it turns out conflicting services are fighting for your dns which means Network Manager doesn't always win.

`apt-get purge rdnssd
apt-get purge resolvconf 
service NetworkManager restart`

Sorted it out for me. Note that your might not have rdnssd or resolvconf installed but if one of them IS, its redundant as Network Manager does their job anyway.