# Ubuntu 15 dns not working

Tags: dns

Got dns probe finished bad config.
How to fix this? 
I have tried `sudo rm /etcresolv.conf` and `sudo resolvconf -u`.

Disabling an enabling network also doesn't fix that problem.
Restarting won't help nether.
I have huawei hg8245h router.

Comment: You mean `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`, right?

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question yesterday, after running into it myself:

[Slow DNS Resolution after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205527/slow-dns-resolution-after-upgrade/676398#676398)

In summary:

```
apt-get purge rdnssd
apt-get purge resolvconf 
service NetworkManager restart
```